# Data Model for addresses with varying number of address lines

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, datamodel

My question:

How would I implement a database design on the back-end and the front-end to accommodate a varying number of address lines such as AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, etc. into infinity while maintaining an intuitive front-end user experience. I want this to maximize the cleanliness and ease of merging documents later on once the database has been developed. Some addresses have only one street line while others can even have five or maybe more.

Background:

I am very new to data modeling and database design. I don't yet understand the consequences that database modeling will have on how the forms on the front-end will have to be designed and the headaches that may go along with a particular design. Therefore, I'm not sure if what I'm seeking is a big mistake.

I'm designing a case management database for a law firm. We plan to create a separate Addresses table and have a many-to-many relationship between the people/entities and the addresses--i.e., many people/entities may have many addresses and the same address may belong to many people/entities.

Thank you!

Comment: "I am very new to data modeling and database design....I'm designing a case management database for a law firm". Please don't take offense to this, but it sounds to me like you're in over your head.  The question you've asked is a very wide and deep topic.  That said, google "database normilisation" and "database 1-n" to get started.  Good luck.

Comment: Could you please discuss specifically the idea of multiple varying street lines within an address data model? I've not seen discussion on this specific idea and I want to make sure I'm not setting myself up for problems down the line when I start working on the user forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, for an address, the data is not normalized over the lines.  So, an address table would just have fields like AddressLine1 and AddressLine2.

The bigger geography information (example:  city, state, country, postal code) would be stored in separate fields in the address record.

The reason for this is quite practical.  Addresses are typically printed, and there is a limited amount of printing space available.  If there are four lines, for instance, you have the name, address line 1, address line 2, and city/state/country/postal code.

If you really needed to store an unlimited number of lines, you would do it with an AddressLines table.  The AddressLines table would have fields, such as:

- AddressId -- the address record it belongs to
- LineNumber
- LineContents

However, this seems like overkill.

Your bigger problem is standardizing addresses.  Have you given that any thought?  (You know:  "101 6th Avenue", "101 Sixth Ave.", and "101 Avenue of the Americas" are all the same address in New York City.)

Comment: What are your suggestions for standardizing the address? : ) Maybe the smarter way would be to just have a single address line, a suite/apartment field, and an optional line or two above the street line that some addresses have like for the name of the building. What do you think is best?

Comment: You can google for address rectification/cleaning/standardization services and software.  These typically do other things, such as appending zip+4s onto the address.  My guess is that an address table with the following fields should be sufficient:  address line 1, address line 2, city, state/province, postal code, country.  However, without standardizing the addresses, trying to share them is ambitious.

Comment: Thank you. I had not considered address standardization and will look into it closely.

Comment: The database is intended to start modestly as a mere repository for case and client data, but evolve over time into something more ambitious and useful. I just want to make sure that I use the right data models from the start to accommodate its continued expansions and development.

Comment: An AddressLines table is not at all overkill. I 'd call it an excellent suggestion especially in light of op's comment, "accommodate a varying number of address lines such as AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, etc. into infinity".  Good answer, +1.